# Sequelize Populate Relation Query Either Table

Tags: javascript, mysql, node.js, sequelize.js

I have the following two tables in Sequelize

```
const Tokens = sequelize.define("Tokens", {
    id: {
        type: DataTypes.UUID,
        defaultValue: DataTypes.UUIDV4,
        primaryKey: true
    },
    active: {
        type: DataTypes.BOOLEAN
    }
});
```

and

```
const User = sequelize.define("Users", {
    id: {
        type: DataTypes.UUID,
        defaultValue: DataTypes.UUIDV4,
        primaryKey: true
    },
    first_name: {
        type: DataTypes.STRING
    }
});

User.associate = models => {
    models["Users"].hasMany(models["Tokens"], {foreignKey: 'userID', as: 'tokens_userid'});
};
```

I'm trying to run the following query in Sequelize.

```
const token = await db.Tokens.findOne({
    where: {
        id,
        active: true
    },
    include: ["tokens_userid"]
});
```

But I'm getting the following error.

```
Error: Association with alias "tokens_userid" does not exists
```

My main goal is to get the user based on a Token ID. Now I would just move that association to the User table, but the problem with that later on I will want to get all the tokens for a given User ID. So I will run into this problem either way.

I tried adding the following line, but it was complaining about circular relations or something like that.

```
models["Tokens"].hasOne(models["User"], {foreignKey: 'userID', as: 'tokens_userid'});
```

How can I query either the Users or Tokens table and have it populate correctly with the relation?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was able to solve this by adding the following line to my table.

```
models["Tokens"].belongsTo(models["User"], {foreignKey: 'userID', as: 'tokens_userid_from_token'});
```

Basically what I tried before but changed `hasOne` to `belongsTo`.

Hopefully this helps someone else.